# Haskell Replicate according to number value

Tags: list, haskell, replication

I have the following problem, I want to replicate numbers according to their value in a list, but if it's lower than 0, they do not appear. For example:

```
myList [1, 4, 3] = [1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3]
myList  [1, 0, 2] = [1, 2, 2]
```

I was thinking of using my version of replicate (which I'm also using for something else so I can't change the  `Int -> a -> [a]`) but I don't know why there is a complication error, please help me fix, but without the use of map.

```
myList:: [Int] -> [Int]
myList [] = []
myList (x:xs) = (myReplicate (if x > 0 then x else 0) x) ++ myReplicate xs

myReplicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
myReplicate 0 x = [ ]
myReplicate count x = x : myReplicate (count-1) x
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You append with `myReplicate xs`, but `xs` is a list of `Int`s. You should recurse on the tail of the list, so:

```
myList:: [Int] -> [Int]
myList [] = []
myList (x:xs) = (myReplicate (if x > 0 then x else 0) x) ++ myList xs
```

This then produces:

```
Prelude> myList [1,4,3]
[1,4,4,4,4,3,3,3]
```

It might be better however to make `myReplicate` work with any `Int`, so:

```
myReplicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
myReplicate n _ | n <= 0 = []
myReplicate count x = x : myReplicate (count-1) x
```

then your `myList` can be simplified to:

```
myList:: [Int] -> [Int]
myList [] = []
myList (x:xs) = myReplicate x x ++ myList xs
```

We can also make use of [**`concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:concatMap):

```
myList:: [Int] -> [Int]
myList = concatMap (\x -> myReplicate x x)
```

we can generalize this further to let this work with any `Foldable`:

```
myList:: Foldable f => f Int -> [Int]
myList = concatMap (\x -> myReplicate x x)
```